# Como acessar o valor de um ponteiro que recebe um endereço?

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória

Como eu acesso o valor de um ponteiro que recebe o endereço de uma variável? Como no seguinte teste:

```
int main()
{
    int     p1;
    int     *p2;
    int     *ptr;

    p1 = 10;
    p2 = &p1;
    ptr = *p2;

    printf("%i\n%i\n%i\n\n", *p2, *ptr, p1);
}
```

Aprendi que ao apontar para o endereço de uma variável com `&`, conseguimos acessar o valor com o operador `*`. Mas e quando a variável já é um ponteiro que recebe um endereço?

Ao compilar o programa, ocorre o erro:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Acho que até entendo o motivo (o ponteiro que estou tentando acessar `p2` não possui um valor e sim recebe apenas o endereço).

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

O problema está na atribuição do valor. Se você quer atribuir algo que é ponteiro para uma variável que espera um ponteiro, por que acha que precisa manipular este valor? Não basta fazer uma atribuição simples?

Os operadores de `*` e `&` não são diferentes de `+`, `-` e outros aritméticos, eles pegam dados, os manipulam por alguma regra e algoritmo estabelecido e dá um resultado. Se você quer o mesmo dado sem manipulá-lo não tem porque fazer alguma operação com esse dado, portanto não tem porque usar um operador nele.

Um bom compilador nem deixaria isso compilar.

O fato de ter atribuído separado da declaração pode ter ajudado um pouco a confundir.

Quando funciona vê que `*p2` imprime `10`, que é o valor apontado por `p2`. Então quando tenta usar o endereço 10 da memória acessa um local que não tem permissão e dá o erro. Já `p2` tem um endereço de memória válido que é o que `ptr` espera, então é só usá-lo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int p1 = 10;
    int *p2 = &p1;
    int *ptr = p2;
    printf("%i\n%i\n%i\n%p", *p2, *ptr, p1, (void *)p2);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7S1LUy). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/dtlrdaumxb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Copy.c).

A não ser que queria fazer outra coisa, mas não tem nada na pergunta que indique isto.